# How to fix AVPlayer position on scrollable view or How to fix it in a view

Tags: ios, avplayer, cgrectmake, avplayerviewcontroller

Do anybody have idea about how to fix AVPlayer position on a scroll-able view i am using the following code to set the AVPlayer frame but when the device size changes it remains of same size on different size and also i have a scrollable view so because of this code i am using the view scrolls in background and player remains fix at a place. Any help is appreciated.

```
   //here is my code

     - (void)viewDidLoad {
          [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *localfilepath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[managedObject valueForKey:@"clip_path"]];

    player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];

    AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];

   [self addChildViewController:controller];
   [self.view addSubview:controller.view];

   controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(10,80,300,250);
   controller.player = player;
   controller.showsPlaybackControls = YES;

   [player pause];

 }
```

Comment: how about implement UIScrollViewDelegate's method - scrollViewDidScroll, in it you can set AVPlayerView's frame

Comment: i am not getting ? how would you do that @J.Hunter

Comment: Another way: don't add avplayer view as scroll view's subview, add avplayer view and scroll view to same view as subview, like avplayer and scroll view are brother view.

Comment: @ J.Hunter here in this code, i am not using any scroll view but if i use the same code on iPhone 5s  it looks fine but if the screen size increases player goes in one corner so i want to make it fix or flexible for all screen sizes

Comment: have you tried auto layout? maybe add four constraint - width, height, centerX and centerY to your avplayer view can resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

like this:

1.your view controller conforms to UIScrollViewDelegate protocol
2.in -    (void)viewDidLoad, set your scroll view's delegate to self, like

```
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
```

3.implement - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView, for example

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    UIView *avplayerView = [self getAVPlayerView];
    avplayerView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 80 + offset.y, 300, 250);
}
```

Hope this helpful